# How performance is enhanced by using final() methods in java

Tags: java, inline, final

I was reading through Java-The Complete Reference,and then I encountered this statement which says that-
**Methods declared as final can sometimes provide a performance enhancement**:
*Reason given is-*

- The compiler is free to inline calls to them because it “knows” they
  will not be overridden by a subclass.
- When a small final method is called, often the Java compiler can copy
  the bytecode
  for the subroutine directly inline with the compiled code of the calling method,
  thus eliminating the costly overhead associated with a method call.
  Inlining is only an option with final methods.

I am not able to understand the second point.Can somebody please explain?What exactly is Inlining?

Comment: The second point is an expansion of the first point. Can you be more specific about what you don't understand?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline/info

Comment: The JVM is at liberty to rewrite code as long as certain rules are followed; basically as long as the overall effect is the same (especially in the executing thread)